# Designing a Silicon Photomultiplier Read-Out circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal-processing, avalanche-breakdown, summer

I'm designing a Silicon Photomultiplier circuit with an amplifier. The base circuit can be shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFmMbl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This was from SensL's recommended circuit layout for their Silicon Photomultiplier, the MicroFJ-60035-TSV. However, this is for one photomultiplier. I designed a board with four photomultipliers, each with their own op amp circuit, but I was wondering, if I used 4 photomultipliers and had their output go to one op amp, would there be any design considerations to think about? You can see the proposed schematic below, though the -30V bias was left out since it would be the same as the previous circuit. At first, I thought that this would act like a summing amplifier, with each photomultiplier contributing a voltage to the op amp; depending on the output voltage, you can detect how many photomultipliers 'fired'. Does this idea seem reasonable, or is there something I'm not taking into consideration?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzXvPE.png)</sup>

EDIT: Below is a revised circuit used in LTspice. I tried modeling the photomultiplier with a pulsed current source in parallel with a capacitor and resistor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwZ8lp.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this idea seem reasonable, or is there something I'm not taking
>   into consideration?

Notice the 3 pF capacitor across the feedback resistor? This is normally chosen to counter the photodiode parasitic capacitance in order to constrain the noise gain of the opamp.

With four photodiodes in parallel, the feedback capacitance would need to rise four times in order to keep the noise back to where it was previously. That means you will also reduce the signal bandwidth to one-quarter.

Maybe you can live with this or maybe you can live with four times the background noise. Only you can say.

Comment: You mean four, right? :)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yes I did. Must be getting senile.

Comment: It was that pesky 3 pf that threw you.

Comment: Must have been lol

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To be honest, I never really considered the parasitic capacitance from the photodiode. I didn't even know that I had to consider it. If I increase the capacitance to 12 pF, the rise time would be longer, but the noise would be better? Would the resistance need to change at all to accommodate the larger capacitance? I'm trying to model this circuit using a voltage source as a substitute for the photodiode, but since it's an ideal source, simulation is not going really well.

Comment: You model it as a current source not a voltage source because the op-amp configuration you are using is a virtual earth inverting current amplifier or TIA (trans impedance amplifier). Never use a voltage source on the inverting input of a linear amplifier because you'll just get garbage.

Comment: 12pF means the noise is the same for a single photodiode. This may or may not be important to you. Resistance can remain the same or quarter (to recover the bandwidth if that is most important).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I never really took a class on operational amplifiers, and my knowledge is pretty much based around the ideal model. I never had to think about noise or bandwidth with these types of circuits before. So, based on your answers, I would need to increase the capacitance by 4x from 3pF to reduce the noise that comes from  the parasitic capacitance from the four photomultipliers, and I would need to reduce the resistance of the feedback resistor in order to achieve the same bandwidth as the original, one photomultiplier circuit. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, you can't have both - you can reduce the noise back to the original value but at the expense of bandwidth or keep the bandwidth but have higher noise but, you can't do both without a fundamental redesign or loss of gain. Try simulating it.

Comment: I tried simulating it like you said. Keeping the resistance at 470 ohms limits the voltage, making the output voltage slower to return back to its steady state value, while decreasing it to 50 ohms makes it faster, more smoother. How would you measure the bandwidth in transient analysis?

Comment: You measure the bandwidth in AC analysis.

Comment: Thanks; since the system is all comprised of DC components, where would you put the small signal AC source in a way that it would make sense for the circuit? Also, I ran some tests, and I found that when a photomultiplier goes off (as simulated as a current source), they would affect the other photomultipliers. Therefore, to reduce their effects on each other, I put in 1k resistors in series with each of the photomultipliers and the inverting input of the op amp.

Comment: Model the stimulus as a current source in parallel with a capacitor equal to the photodiodes capacitance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried what you said, but the AC analysis didn't reveal anything regarding the bandwidth when I looked at the output signal, even after I performed FFT on the output signal in my new schematic. Each current source has a small AC signal component, but the simulation output signal didn't tell much with regard to the bandwidth. The DC analysis did work as I expected, with the multiple sources cascading together to increase the output depending on which sources are active.

Comment: Do an ac analysis not a transient analysis.

Comment: I tried an AC analysis like you said, but how can you tell the bandwidth from it? The signal starts low at -60 dB, and as the frequency increases, the output rises to -19 dB at around 107 MHz. It decreases, and then it eventually rises to a steady state value of -24 dB. This is just a sweep from 1 to 7 GHz, since I don't think that I have to worry about high frequencies too much. The FFT of the output signal doesn't tell much at all; it only shows the output as a flat, straight line at 0 V.

Comment: Please show a link to the AC analysis as a picture. 4fF for your photodiode capacitance sounds remarkably low. An FFT does not give you the bandwidth of the amplifier.

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness of my answers. Here is a link to a folder with some screenshots of my simulation. You should be able to see the schematic as well as results of my simulation, both transient and AC analysis.   
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8_U5aaAFBjwdW54SXJJYUdRSlk

Comment: I've been doing some research here on my own, and based on what I read, the configuration that I have right now is an active low pass filter. Now, you mentioned previously that excess noise would be coming from the increased number of photomultipliers from 1 to 4. Based on the design with 1 PM, the cutoff frequency based on the formula (1./(1+j*omega*R*C)) is approximately 66.7 MHz, giving it a really wide bandwidth. As we increase the capacitance, the bandwidth grows smaller, but the cutoff frequency is still in MHz range. Would reducing the resistance help increase the speed of the signal?